# SqlAlchemy UserDefinedType based on built-in type, with additional method

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have class `Foo` which is defined as:

```
class Foo(object):
    def bar(self):
       pass
```

I want to extend sqlalchemy type:

```
class MyUnicode(Foo, sqlalchemy.Unicode):
    def bar(self):
        print "MyUnicode::bar"
```

and define table like this:

```
Base = declarative_base()
class Table(Base):
   __tablename__ = "Table"

   first  = Column(Unicode(16))
   second = Column(MyUnicode(16))
```

Finaly, I want to be able use it as here:

```
t = query(Table).first()
t.bar()
```

The problem is probably with TypeEngine, because debugger show that `t` is type of `unicode` not `MyUnicode` or even `sqlalchemy.Unicode`

I tried do this by:

```
class myunicode(Foo, unicode):
    def bar(self):
        print "myunicode::bar"

class MyUnicode(sqlalchemy.Unicode):

    @property
    def python_type(self):
        return myunicode
```

but this doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't know off hand... do you have a stacktrace... maybe we can find the error in the [sqlalchemy code](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy)

Comment: I got message: `AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'bar'`

Comment: Well that sounds a bit different than what you thought was the error. Do you have a **full** stack trace??

Comment: yes, I have, but is not related to sqlalchemy. It simply shows that I can't use bar method on `python unicode` type, because `unicode` does not have this method. This simply shows that my code does not take any effects, and `MyUnicode` type still use `unicode`, not my `myunicode` wraper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you'll need to overwrite `def result_processor(self, dialect, coltype):` because the type that you get from the database is still just a unicode string and you'll have to convert that into your python type.

Something like this:

```
def result_processor(self, dialect, coltype):
    def process(value):
        if value is not None:
            return MyUnicode(value)   # value is a regular unicode string
        else:
            return MyUnicode()
    return process
```